# Excel file isn't updated by code, until I manually go in and save it. Then the code does work

Tags: vb.net

I searched far and wide, but can't find a solution to my problem.
I am using Excel 2016 and xlsx files, and sometimes (I can't reproduce this), the excel files gets 'locked' or something similar.

I narrowed it down to a very basic script where I don't do anything else but press a button where underneath is the following code:

> ```
>         Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Projecten\Test.xlsx;Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""
>
>         Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
>         Dim updateStatement As String = "UPDATE [Rondelijst$] SET [interval] = 'Maandelijks' WHERE [KKS] = 'GKC20AT001'"
>         Dim command As New OleDbCommand(updateStatement, connection)
>
>         connection.Open()
>         command.ExecuteNonQuery()
>         connection.Close()
> ```

When I run the code I don't get an error message, it just goes through everything without a problem.

This isn't working, until I manually go into the Excel sheet, and press save.
I don't do anything else: just go in and press save.  After this is works like a charm.  Until certain period, but like I said before: I can't reproduce what is causing it.

What can be the reason behind this? Is the excel file in a wrong data format or older/inaccessable version?
And more importantly, how can I solve this without a manual action (now and then)?

The excel file can be found at: http://www.bradydownloads.com/techsupport/Test.xlsx

Comment: Is the `Dim connectionString As String` statement entered in your code as you have shown above as a multi-line statement?  If so, I am surprised that it works at at all as you have split the line within a an open string.  This inserts a new-line  (CrLf) at each split point and should yield an invalid connection string.

Comment: No it is one line.  It gots corrupted when pasting it.  I have edited it now.

Comment: Wonder if it's related to the Excel Application Interactive property? Also I would recommend wrapping that connection and command in `Using`.

Comment: If it is, how can I fix it?